# How to disable accessing internet particular programmes (Aplllication) in windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8

I'm using limited data size broadband connections. So I want to disable all programmes (applications) to accessing internet in windows 8 other than browsers. so that  I can save data usage by unwanted application.

Answer (score 1):

The WinRT applications are sandboxed, which means they have a limited range of operations within the system and those operations interact with the application itself, only.

You cannot dictate to close an existing app which is running from a WinRT app. Only the user can do this.

At most, you should try to get the status of the network usage and if it is high, show the user a specific message, something like : At the moment, the data usage is relatively high, for better experience, try to close some the apps which cause this.